# Style d3 svg line with css

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, styles, line

I want to style my d3 line element with CSS. It seems to work just fine for other elements like "rect", "path" or "circle" but for "line" I just can't make it work...

css:

```
.line {
   stroke: #000000;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}
```

js:

```
d3.select('.container')
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", "0")
  .attr("x2", "100")
  .attr("y1", "0")
  .attr("y2", "100")
  //.attr("style", "stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5")
```

If I remove the comment in the last line it works, but I don't want to use inline CSS.

Seems to me like you can't set the stroke attribute of specifically a line without using inline css...

Am I missing something?

Comment: `line` is not a class, but an SVG element. That being said, remove that dot: `line{stroke: #000000;stroke-width: 0.5;}`.

Comment: That did it. thanks a bunch! I guess I only used css on classes so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the dot...

```
line {
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
}
```

In CSS, a class uses a dot like `.my-class` elements have nothing in front of them e.g. `line` or `div` and IDs have `#` like `#my-id`